unpacking .basis texture to any other format
i'm trying to unpack a .basis texture file to any other format (ideally .exr) for use in blender.
i have a model i extracted from some website, being a glTF referencing .basis textures. blender cannot handle .basis textures so i need to convert them to any other format it can read.
i tries using basisu (https://github.com/BinomialLLC/basis_universal), to convert first to pngs. this worked, however the tool is very clumsy and some documentation is lacking, and exports hundreds of PNGs (where i need just 1 of them), which would require a lot of manual work deleting unnecessary files. it worked, but i suspect the PNGs destroy color information/bit depth.
i next tried to instead use it to convert the files directly to .ktx, then convert these to EXR files. however, basisu seems to convert to ktx 1.0, while i cannot find any tool (that i can either use from the CLI or python) that handles ktx 1, only ktx 2.
